# Calling an Action Method based on the value of DropDownList and the model

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a dropdownlist in my View. I need to enable the user to select a value from the dropdownlist and click a button/ActionLink to call another action method in the same controller. The values that needs to be passed to the new ActionMethod are the ID of the selected Value from the dropdownlist and also the ID of the model which is being passed into the View. The model and the Dropdownlist are not linked together by any means.

I have tried `onchnage = document.location.href` to set the path of the action method and pass a single value to the action method. But the issue with document.location.href is that it appends the url to the existing url which is not appreciated; i.e, the final url turns out be `localhost:port/controller1/action1/controller1/action2` which should have been simply `localhost:port/controller1/action2`

I am looking for a way where it could be done without using javascript as I have already tried it.

**Code in the View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Copy","SetValues",FormMethod.Post))
{
    <p>
        @Html.DropDownList("OptionValueID", null, "Select")
        <input type="submit" value="Copy" />

        //This is the preferable method though
        @*@Html.ActionLink("Copy", "Copy", "SetValues", new { @OptionValueID = @ViewBag.id,@CopyID = CopyDDL.SelectedValue},null)*@
    </p>
}
```

The copy function is going to take two arguments: `Id of the selected item` and `ID that is being passed through ViewBag.id`

The View that is being returned by View would a different View

**JavaScript** that I have tried

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function copy(_OptionValueID)
    {
        var url = "/SetValues/Copy";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: { copyid: _OptionValueID},
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) { }


        });
        response();
    }
</script>
```

It doesn't evaluate at all.

**Action Method that calls this View**

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
        var ov = db.OptionValue.Include(x => x.Option).FirstOrDefault(x => x.OptionValueID == id);
        var opid = ov.OptionID;
        var op = db.Option.Include(x => x.TechnicalCharacteristic).FirstOrDefault(x => x.OptionID == opid);
        var tcid = op.TechnicalCharacteristicID;
        var tc = db.TechnicalCharacteristic.Include(x => x.TcSets).FirstOrDefault(x => x.TechnicalCharacteristicID == tcid);
        var tcset = tc.TcSets;
        var opv = db.OptionValue.FirstOrDefault(x => x.OptionValueID == id);
        ViewBag.OptionValue = opv.OptionVal;
        ViewBag.Option = opv.Option.OptionName;
        ViewBag.Lsystem = opv.Option.Lsystem.LsystemName;
        ViewBag.FamilyName = opv.Option.Lsystem.LsystemFamily.FamilyName;
        ViewBag.OptionValID = id;
        ViewBag.OptionID = opv.OptionID;
        var setValue = db.SetValue.Where(x=>x.OptionValueID==id).OrderBy(x=>x.TcSet.SetName);
        ViewBag.OptionValueID = new SelectList(db.OptionValue.Where(x=>x.OptionID==opid), "OptionValueID", "OptionVal");
        return View(setValue.ToList());
}
```

I ahve checked most question relating to this, but none had the overhead of passing two parameters without using a model.

**UPDATE: making it more clear**

```
 public ActionResult copy(int OptionValueID,int CopyID)
 {
     //do Something
     return View("Error");
 }
```

Above is the Copy Method

```
OptionValueID = ViewBag.OptionValID //Got from the Action Method Index of SetValues
CopyID = Value from the DropDownlist
```

**Edit Based on Answer**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Copy","SetValues",FormMethod.Post))
{
    <p>
        @Html.DropDownList("CopyID", null, "Select")
        <button type="submit" id="Copy" data-id="@ViewBag.OptionValID"> Copy </button>
    </p>
}
```

now the page is being redirected but the no parameters are being passed. Should I be adding routevalues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it without javascript. Your `ActionLink()` method is parsed on the server before its sent to the client, so any route values are the initial values in the controller, not any edited values the user makes in the view. In order to respond to client side events you need javascript.

You can use ajax to post the values to the server method.

Include a button and handle its click event

```
<button type="button" id="Copy" data-id="@ViewBag.id">Copy</button>
```

Script

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Copy", "SetValues")';
$('#Copy").click(function() {
  var optionID = $(this).data('id');
  var copyID = $('#OptionValueID').val();
  $.get(url, { OptionValueID: optionID, copyID : CopyID }, function(response) {
    // do something with the response
  });
});
```

or alternatively if you wanting to redirect, then replace the `$.get()` with

```
location.href = url + '?OptionValueID=' + optionID + '&CopyID=' + copyID;
```

**Edit**

Based on revised question and comments, if you wanting to post and redirect, there is no need for any javascript or the link. The dropdownlist needs to be `@Html.DropDownList("CopyID", null, "Select")` so that its selected value is bound to method parameter `int CopyID` and since the `OptionValueID` is not edited, then either add its value as a route parameter in the form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Copy", "SetValues", new { OptionValueID = ViewBag.OptionID }, FormMethod.Post))
```

or add a hidden input for the value

```
<input type="hidden" name="OptionValueID" value="@ViewBag.OptionID" />
```

Comment: I need to return another View when the Copy is selected. So i should be using `Location.href` right? But nothing is being returned nor the function is called. Currently I have nothing to display in my `Copy` but I suppose the error page should be displayed if the function is beig called. And when I debug in the browser why is the Script that I ahve written not being shown?

Comment: Now I don't get what your wanting to do. If you really do want to redirect, then just use a normal submit (i.e. the submit button you already have). All you need to do is add a route value in the form - i.e. `new { Html.BeginForm("Copy","SetValues", new { OptionValueID  = ViewBag.id }, FormMethod.Post)` and then rename your dropdown to `@Html.DropDownList("CopyID", null, "Select")`

Comment: As for your script, there is nothing in your code that call that function

Comment: I have updated the question for a better explanation and the code that i changed based on your above comment. But you told I could simply use a Submit to get things done. I changed it just now after your comment.. is something like this possible `<button type="submit" id="Copy" data-id="{OptionValueID = @ViewBag.OptionValID,CopyID = CopyID.Val()}"> Copy </button>`

Comment: How have you set the value of `location.href`? The code I have shown will certainly not generate the url you claim - it will be `/SetValues/Copy?OptionValueID=someValue&CopyID=anotherValue`. But as I noted above, you should just be using a normal submit - javascript is not really necessary if you just intending to do a redirect.

Comment: And as for your edit, the selected dropdown value will be passed to the parameter `CopyID `, but `OptionValID` will not - you need to add it as a route value as noted above (or you can just add a hidden input for it - `<input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.OptionValID" />`)

Comment: `location.href = url + '?OptionValueID=' + OptionValueID + '&CopyID=' + copyID;`. I do not know something else should have been added.  The value for COpyID is beign passed to the function, but optionValueID. I tried `input type="hidden"` as well. But how does the function know the hidden input should be assigned to the function parameter?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `name="OptionValueID"` from the hidden input in my last comment (which is how the `DefaultModelBinder` matches the name of the form controls to the name of your parameters

Comment: Yes now it is working :) thanks again. Do you wanna edit your answer to add this into it? or i can also edit for you